# Bash | Append file numbering as script loops through an array of files

Tags: bash

Trying to append an index number of every element in my array. This to show which file is busy copying, or rather how many are left to copy.

```
for files in "${source}"${file_extensions_to_copy} ; do 

echo "copying file 1 of 10" 

cp -ap "${files}" "${destination}"
```

Solution:

```
echo "copying file $((index + 1)) of ${#files[@]}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
source_dir=/path/to/source
destination_dir=/path/to/destination
ext=*.txt
files=( "$source_dir/"$ext )

for index in "${!files[@]}"; do
  echo "copying file $((index + 1)) of ${#files[@]}"
  cp -ap "${files[index]}" "$destination_dir"
done
```

Note that arrays are zero-based, so you have to add 1 to each index.